# Create Jenkinsfile from "execute shell" commands

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a series of `Execute shell` boxes on a Jenkins build. After 3 days of Google and watching videos I need help. I am more a sysadmin than a coder so I'm having difficulty in creating a Jenkinsfile with the correct options and syntax. Can anyone advise? I need to create a pipeline. Anything in `<name>` is like that for security reasons, I have the real values in the files.

Execute shell

`mkdir -p deploy`

Execute shell

```
cp -R code/api deploy/
cp docker/Dockerfile.dev deploy/
(cd deploy/api/<Name>.<Name>.Web/ && aws s3 cp --recursive --region=eu-west-1 s3://config.<name>/audience-view/atg/dev/API/ .)
```

Execute shell

`cd deploy && docker build -t <name> -f Dockerfile.dev .`

Execute shell

```
aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-1 > docker_login.sh && chmod +x 
docker_login.sh && ./docker_login.sh
docker tag <name>:latest 543573289192.dkr.ecr.eu-west-
1.amazonaws.com/<name>:latest
docker push <name>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<name>:latest
```

Execute shell

```
docker rmi audience-view-dev-api
docker rmi 543573289192.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<name>:latest
```

Execute shell

```
RUNNING_TASKS=$(aws ecs list-tasks --region=eu-west-1 --cluster <name> --family <name> --query 'taskArns')
if [ "$RUNNING_TASKS" != "[]" ]; then
TASK_ARN=$(aws ecs list-tasks --region=eu-west-1 --cluster a<name> --family <name> --query 'taskArns[0]' | sed 's/\"//g')
aws ecs stop-task --region=eu-west-1 --cluster=<name> --task=$TASK_ARN --reason="Deployment from Jenkins" 
while [ $RUNNING_TASKS != "[]" ]; do
    sleep 5
    RUNNING_TASKS=$(aws ecs list-tasks --region=eu-west-1 --cluster <name> --family <name> --query 'taskArns')
done
fi
```

Execute shell

```
TASK_ARN=$(aws ecs start-task --region=eu-west-1 --cluster <name> --task-definition <name> --container-instances 5f0c5b75-64a2-45cf-8ced-d6a6d13d2666 --query 'tasks[0].taskArn' | sed 's/arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:543573289192:task\///' | sed 's/\"//g')
TASK_STATUS=$(aws ecs describe-tasks --region=eu-west-1 --cluster <name> --tasks $TASK_ARN --query 'tasks[0].lastStatus')
while [ $TASK_STATUS == "PENDING" ]; do
echo $TASK_STATUS
TASK_STATUS=$(aws ecs describe-tasks --region=eu-west-1 --cluster <name> --tasks $TASK_ARN --query 'tasks[0].lastStatus' | sed 's/\"//g')
if [ $TASK_STATUS == "STOPPED" ]; then
    echo $(aws ecs describe-tasks --region=eu-west-1 --cluster <name> --tasks $TASK_ARN --query 'tasks[0].containers[0].exitCode')
    exit 1
fi
done
```

Comment: I consider it better to have the source in any RCS (preferably git nowadays).  Your Jenkins job should check out the project and call one script.  That can either do everything you pasted into your question above or call a bunch of other scripts, each doing one of the blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins is best used as the glue to connect all the build pieces together, not the build script itself. As Alfe mentioned, it would be best to have this all in a shell script and then run the shell script with Jenkins.

BUT, if you really want to do this in a Pipeline job, it would look something like this (declarative pipeline):

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('setup') {
            steps {
                sh "mkdir -p deploy"
            }
        stage('nextStage') {
            steps {
                sh """
                    cp -R code/api deploy/
                    cp docker/Dockerfile.dev deploy/
                    (cd deploy/api/<Name>.<Name>.Web/ && aws s3 cp --recursive --region=eu-west-1 s3://config.<name>/audience-view/atg/dev/API/ .)
                """
            }
        }
        stage('anotherStage') {
            steps {
                echo "repeat for all your shell steps"
            }
        }
    }
}
```